# Clear Flink state with window closing

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Here's my code.
My question is as follows

- Is it correct to clear state in this way?
- Is this the correct way to use keyBy ？

  //There are 1000,000 + storeId

  ```
   orderStream.keyBy(Order::getStoreId)
       .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.days(1), Time.hours(16)))
       .trigger(ContinuousEventTimeTrigger.of(Time.seconds(1)))
       .evictor(TimeEvictor.of(Time.seconds(0), true))
       .process(new ProcessWindowFunction<Order, Object, Long, TimeWindow>() {
           MapState<Long, Long> storeCountState;
           @Override
           public void process(Long storeId, Context context, Iterable<Order> elements, Collector<Object> out) throws Exception {
               long sum = 0L;
               for (Order element : elements) {
                   sum++;
               }
               storeCountState.put(storeId, storeCountState.get(storeId) + sum);
           }

           @Override
           public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
               super.open(parameters);
               MapStateDescriptor<Long, Long> mapStateDescriptor = new MapStateDescriptor();
               storeCountState = getRuntimeContext().getMapState(mapStateDescriptor);
           }

           @Override
           public void close() throws Exception {
               super.close();
               // I clear state when each window close 
               storeCountState.clear();
           }
       })
       .addSink(new PrintSinkFunction<>());
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should override the `public void clear(Context context) throws Exception {}` function, not the `close()` function.

[Documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#using-per-window-state-in-processwindowfunction)